# Testing enums outside the Controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, enums

I have a enum in my Controller but I can't access this enum from inside the test spec using vm.MyEnum as enum is defined outside the controller class.

```js
export enum EditType {
  NO_EDITED = 0, ANNOTATED = 1, SIGNED = 2
}
export class MyCtrl extends AppCtrl {
  .......
}
```

I can't create a global variable inside my test as it says I can't do so in strict mode. How do I get it inside my 'describes' . Thank you :)

Comment: How are you importing `MyCtrl` and `EditType` in your test spec?

Comment: `  beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
    controller = _$controller_;
  }));    .    .    .
  beforeEach(function() {
    vm = controller("MyCtrl", {$scope: scope });
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it quite easily. I just had to insert the variable not inside the controller's scope in `beforeEach`function before initiating the controller. (I'm using SystemJS module loader. Other module loaders might have different configurations)

```js
beforeEach(function() {
  EditType = System.registry.get(System.normalizeSync('app/pdfeditor/pdfviewer.controller')).EditType;
});
```

Then I started injecting stuffs using another `beforeEach`

```js
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
  controller = _$controller_;
}));
beforeEach(function() {
  vm = controller("MyCtrl", {
    $scope: scope
  });
});
```